# Scalability problem of blockchain

Tags: scalability

In the blockchain, all the data will be stored permanently but is there no limit to storing data on the entire network? Because the number of nodes to control the network won't increase to infinity but the data will. So I wonder what's gonna happen in the future.

Comment: I'm sure wildly speculative and opinionated answers may be coming your way.